# fold pairs into map of set; create map entries if not existing already

Tags: kotlin

using a list of pairs, want to transform them to a map of sets.

input: list of pairs is like this

```
listOf(Pair('bob', UGLY), Pair('sue', PETTY), Pair('bob', FAT))
```

desired output is a map of set where the key is `first` of pair, and the set is the `second`

```
mapOf('bob' to setOf(UGLY, FAT), 'sue' to setOf(PETTY))
```

I have tried this, but wow this is incredibly verbose. can this be reduced?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var m = HashMap<Int, MutableSet<Int>>()
    listOf(1 to 1, 2 to 2, 1 to 3).map {
        val set = m.getOrPut(it.first, { listOf<Int>().toMutableSet() })
        set.add(it.second)
        set
    }
    println (m)
}
-> {1=[1, 3], 2=[2]}

// yet another version, yields the correct result, but I feel a lack of clarity 
// that maybe I'm missing a library function that would suit the purpose.
listOf(1 to 1, 2 to 2, 1 to 3).fold(m, {
    mapSet, pair ->
    val set = mapSet.getOrPut(pair.first, { listOf<Int>().toMutableSet() })
    set.add(pair.second)
    mapSet
})
-> {1=[1, 3], 2=[2]}
```

Comment: in the question you ask for a map of sets: `mapOf('bob' to setOf(UGLY, FAT), ..`, but the code in your example produces a map of lists: `{1=[1, 3], 2=[2]}`. Which one did you mean? Please choose one and correct the other.

Comment: the concept is what is important. please don't get hung up bob being fat and ugly because, although true, it's just an abstraction.

Comment: it is always nice to be specific, you know. Please see the suggested edit

Comment: your edit goes against my intent. I want a set of results

Comment: am I to believe you assume that a square bracket means list? if that is the case, just print a set for yourself in kotlin and you'll see [...]

Comment: yep, my bad. Sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` and then a `mapValues` like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val pairs = listOf(Pair("bob", "UGLY"), Pair("sue", "PETTY"), Pair("bob", "FAT"))
    val result = pairs
            .groupBy { it.first }
            .mapValues { it.value.map { p -> p.second }.toSet() }
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: @activedecay That is fine if he gives his best answer first, then alternatives.  But not as an "EDIT:" trail that must be followed to understand the final answer -- that is less clear and is like reading only commit logs to understand the final code.  We don't need to see history in the answer itself, just the final answer since we can view edit history any time.  This was a simplified case and was a "maybe" thing, others are much worse.